# Maven3- How to tell maven to use latest versions using verions-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.2.5. I have a multi module project with parent P and sub-modules A(jar), B(war), C(EAR). I want to always use the latest version of dependency as we do nightly builds to QA environments. We could achieve this in Maven2 by using 'LATEST' in place of version number. But looks like this feature is disabled in MAVEN3. Now I am trying to make use of "use-latest-versions" goal in versions-maven-plugin.

I am trying to run this plugin on modules B and C so that module B will use latest artifact from module A and module C will use latest artifact from module B to build final EAR.

```
    **My parent POM** 
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>GGGGGGG</groupId>
        <artifactId>JARJARAJR</artifactId>
        <version>19.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <name>JARJARAJR</name>

//Modules of this project
        <modules>
            <module>../../../Module A</module>
            <module>../../../Module Bs</module>
            <module>../../../Module C</module>
        </modules>

    <build>
            <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>update-dependency-versions</id>
//Asking maven to run this goal in 'pre-clean' phase
                            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>use-latest-versions</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                        <excludeReactor>false</excludeReactor>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>

    The command I am using to run parent POM is : **mvn -U clean install -P devb -    Dmaven.test.skip=true**
```

I am trying to invoke "use-latest-versions" goal in the "pre-clean" phase(I tried validate and initialize phases too).Bu after module A is built, maven tried to resolve the old version of Module B without running goal "use-latest-versions" for 'versions-maven-plugin".

**In which phase should I run "use-latest-versions" goal so that maven updates the dependency version in Module B before trying to build it?**

Comment: If you are using a multi module build which are built within the same reactor you don't need to use versions maven plugin. BTW: Can you create an example project of that on github to see what you really like to achieve?

Comment: without using versions maven plugin how does maven know to use the latest dependencies?

Comment: So let use define things. Are you using a multi module build like this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee/ ? Please anwer the question with yes or not...

Comment: Yes, I am using a multi-module project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I achieved what I am looking for(Always take latest versions of dependencies):

I have setup a pre-step to "invoke top level maven targets" in jenkins and triggers the command:

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions -DallowSnapshots=true -DexcludeReactor=false
```

on the parent pom
This will update the dependency versions in the parent POM and all its child POM's.
Thank you khmarbaise for trying to help me. I appreciate your time.